# Implode with double quotes as separator

Tags: php, implode

I have this right now:

```
$_words = "'".implode("','", $array_of_words)."'";
```

Which gives me a string like:

```
'word','word2','word3'
```

How can I modify that to get

```
"word","word2","word3"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just swap your quotes

```
$_words = '"'.implode('","', $array_of_words).'"';
```

Comment: You forgot to swap starting and ending quotes :)

Comment: They are actually because what you wrote echoes `'word","word2","word3'`

Comment: I changed it. It wasn't important to show them the solution to their problem but it makes sense to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array();
foreach ($array_of_words as $a1) {
    $result[]='"'.$a1.'"';
}
$_words = implode( ',', $result );
echo $_words;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_words = implode( "','", $array_of_words );`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are generally considered to be of low quality.